# Android - IOS Style Background

Tags: android, ios

I searched for it, but couldn't find any result.

What I want to know is the transparency background like on iPhone when you open menu from down for **android**.

It looks like this.

https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/8a/22/d3/8a22d35bb4983778fea3d3c9845c61a8.jpg

http://orig15.deviantart.net/50e5/f/2013/217/9/0/ios_7_like_background_by_kyroapps-d6gudzf.png

Comment: use custom image for this

Comment: I can't, because the the background of the view should take a bit color of the images from background (so transparent). Like there's a black hat and the layout is blue. The layout should be a bit transparent. Like on image.

Comment: You can likely use a PNG with partial transparency, which will allow the background colors to show through.

Comment: Can you give me an example? Because in design I have no experience.

Comment: use this image as the backround -- http://orig15.deviantart.net/50e5/f/2013/217/9/0/ios_7_like_background_by_kyroapps-d6gudzf.png  - and add a frame layout to cover the backround with semi transparent background color of your choise --  like the dialog here -- https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/1064

Comment: to add to my comment You will get something like this -- http://www.deviantart.com/art/iOS-7-Application-406363258

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you need blur effect for background (not only transparent)
here is some libs that can help you:
https://android-arsenal.com/tag/176

hope it helps

Comment: That's what I mean. Thanks!